# Keepalived alternative for Solaris 10

Tags: solaris, load-balancing, haproxy, application-server, keepalive

We are considering an architecture like the one in the picture for Solaris 10

[image: Architecture]

That is, high avalaibility software load balancers in front of web and application servers.

Unfortunately, Keepalived is not available for Solaris at the moment.

Is there an equivalent artifact for substituing Keepalived which is supported in Solaris 10? Is there an equivalent architecture for Solaris using HA SW load balancing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can look at Solaris Cluster :

http://www.sun.com/software/solaris/cluster/

Comment: Any experience with Solaris Cluster and HTTP software load balancing?

Comment: On HTTP software failover yes but not on load balancing sorry.